# To Find Duplicate files using latest in Linux

Tags: bash, shell, duplicates

I have tried the following code and with that i couldnt achieve what i want.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
find ./ -type f \( -iname "*.xml" \) | sort -n > fileList
sed -i '/\.\/fileList/d' fileList
NAMEOFTHISFILE=$(echo $0|sed -e 's/[]\/()$*.^|[]/\\&/g')
sed -i "/$NAMEOFTHISFILE/d" fileList
cp fileList auxFileList
while read FILENAME
do
    sed -i '1d' auxFileList
    #echo "Comparing $FILENAME with :"
    #Read the aux file and compare current file with every other element in the file
    while read COMPFILENAME
    do
        RETURN=$(diff $FILENAME $COMPFILENAME)
        if [ "$RETURN" == "" ]
        then
        cat $FILENAME | awk ' BEGIN { FS="_" } { printf( "%03d\n",$2) }' | sort | awk ' { printf( "data_%d_box\n", $1)  }'
         #echo "$FILENAME AND $COMPFILENAME are identical"
         #rm -r $FILENAME
        fi
        #echo "  $COMPFILENAME"
    done<auxFileList
done<fileList
rm fileList auxFileList &>/dev/null
printf '\n\n'
```

this code selecting all the files initially. I have to amend my code in such a way that only recent modified filename patterns for example

```
File 1: AAA_555_0000 
File 2: AAAA_123_123 
File 3: AAAA_452_452 [latest]

File 4: BBB_555_0000 
File 5: BBB_555_555 
File 6: BBB_999_999 [latest]

File 7: CCC_555_0000 
File 8: CCC_000_000 
File 9: CCC_000_111 [latest]
```

Script has to pick latest file in all the filename patterns in the folder and it should compare and delete the duplicates.

Appreciate if you can help me with this logic.

Thanks much!

Comment: How about using `ls -ltr` to check latest files and copy them to new location

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nearly 1 million files are there and thats why this requirement arises to automate. Appreciate if you suggest me on how to update this on script.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what do you consider as a file pattern (like 1st 3 matching characters or something else) and does latest file mean file with latest timestamp?

Comment: yes first few characters in the filename. I told AAA as example only but the actual file is "ARCZ00300_010117_1504690829222.xml" "ARCZ00305_010117_1507101657610.xml" ... etc many such filename patterns nearly 1 million files need to be housekept. Appreciate your suggestions on this. Thank you.

Comment: Many commands will not work great with that many files.  You should look into find.  With the -name option, -atime, -ctime, -mtime (according to what you need), you can filter on filename and times.

Comment: find mtime is not appropriate as one file was updated in jun 2017 another filepattern series updated may 2017. name option means u r referring to hardcoding the filenamepattern? 1 million files are there and different different filename pattern series

Comment: I am completely struck in how to fetch the latest file for example ARCZ00300_010117_1504690829222, ARCZ00300_010217_1504690839222,ARCZ00300_020117_2504690829222 (latest), if one file is latest in any series how to pick that latest file in that specific filename pattern series same way other filepatterns also it has to pick latest (newly modified file). appreciate your suggestion on this